# difficulty in selecting elements in a python list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've been trying to clean a txt file, and I'm almost done with it. I have a problem with the list - I cannot select elements of the list I created in `process_line()`, at the line with `###`.

Below is a snippet of the code;

```
def process_line(line):
    # receiving a line or string as function
    # argument and replacing '-' 'D00-D09' & 'F00-F09' to '' if it exists
    line = re.sub('D0+\d|F0+\d|-', '', line)
    seq = str(line.split())
    line = re.sub('\'|\\[|\\]|,', '', seq)
    ###  line = (seq[0] + '|' seq[3] + '-' seq[5]) # this is for shorter lines
    print line
    return line  + '\n'
```

Here is a sample set of data after removing some unwanted data

```
12asA   1  A    4  A  330 
12asB   1  B    4  B  330 
12caA   1  A    5  A  260 
12e8H   1  H    1  H  113   1  H  114  H  212   H  213  H  214  (2)
12e8L   1  L    1  L  107   1  L  108  L  211   L  212  L  214  (3)
```

I was hoping to achieve a format like this, however I need to learn how to extract the elements needed - so I can rearrange the data to the required format:

```
12asA|4-330
12asB|4-330
12caA|5-260
12e8H|1-113,114-212
12e8l|1-107, 108-211
```

instead of getting eg. `23reA|1-14,56-65` I get something `[2|1-A]`

Comment: Why not just do `line='|'.join(line.split())` after `line = re.sub('D0+\d|F0+\d|-', '', line)`

Comment: Could you provide an example `line`?

Comment: Can you provide sample input for line?

Comment: Always use raw strings (`r"..."`) for regular expressions.

Comment: I don't understand the `str` part of the `seq = str(line.split())` line.  `line.split()` breaks `line` up into the pieces I think you want-- there's no need to make a string out of it, and then remove the brackets and quotes you introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but this appears to match your desired output:

```
import re

data = '''
12asA   1  A    4  A  330  
12asB   1  B    4  B  330 
12caA   1  A    5  A  260 
12e8H   1  H    1  H  113   1  H  114  H  212   H  213  H  214  (2)
12e8L   1  L    1  L  107   1  L  108  L  211   L  212  L  214  (3)
'''
lines = filter(None, data.split('\n')) # filter to remove blank lines

def process_line(line):
    line = re.sub(r'D0\d|F0\d|-', '', line)
    for char in "'[],":
        line = line.replace(char, '')
    seq = line.split()
    if len(seq) == 6:
        return '{}|{}-{}'.format(seq[0], seq[3], seq[5])
    elif len(seq) == 16:
        return '{}|{}-{},{}-{}'.format(seq[0], seq[3], seq[5], seq[8], seq[10])

result = [process_line(line) for line in lines]
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
12asA|4-330
12asB|4-330
12caA|5-260
12e8H|1-113,114-212
12e8L|1-107,108-211
```

The following regex in your code:

```
line = re.sub('\'|\\[|\\]|,', '', seq)
```

is a real mess. I have replaced it with a sequence of simple `str.replace` calls instead. In future, when writing regular expressions, please use raw strings (e.g. `r'...'`) for readability and to help you avoid bugs.

If you only added that line to get rid of the brackets, commas, and quotes introduced by calling `str(line.split())` (rather than to deal with garbage in your original data), you should go ahead and remove its equivalent in the code I posted, because it does nothing useful.

Comment: thanks a ton senshin. i will work on the snippet you provided. if it would help clarify things, seq[1] & seq[6] are indicators as to how many fragments in a group. output is identifier|group1|group2. if case of the 1st 3 datelines it has 1 fragment and the last 2 should have 2 groups... sorry, i made an  error in presenting the wrong output... it should be 12e8H|1-107|108-212... some of the data has 2 to 3 fragments in a group... but i really appreciate your help! it kinda created a new logic path!

Comment: Hi senshin! I wanted do use an if statement to query if seq[1] = 1, how to i code it?